# Django: read-only field in form not submitted

Tags: django, forms, widget, textinput

In my form I have one read-only field. The content of the field will be filled by a java script and depends on the input to the editable fields. To avoid that users modify the field data, I would like to mark it as read-only.

When I mark the field as read-only in my forms.py with

```
'key': forms.TextInput(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}),
```

it seems that the content of the field is read-only, but will not be submitted. I get the following error when I try to read form.cleaned_data['key']:

```
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    "Key 'key' not found in <QueryDict: ...>
```

**Is there any better way to mark the field as 'read-only' in the Django form than 'disabled'?**

Thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: It seems that

'key': forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'True'}),

will solve it.

Sorry, should have read further in the docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabled fields are never submitted in form data. But you can use, attribute `readonly="readonly"` , its [supported](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) in almost all browsers.

Also it would be helpful referring this article http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/readonly.html.

Happy Coding.

Comment: The problem with `readonly` is that it does not work with some input types e.g. checkbox or select.